# jQuery can't access a DOM element using ID but can with .class

Tags: jquery, debugging, dom

I posted a similar question earlier and received some good suggestions.  After further investigation, I found that the behavior is different enough to warrant a new question.

I am looking for suggestions as to the best way to debug some odd jQuery behavior.

The following code sample works as expected [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x27Y9/) when appending to the ul by either ID or class reference.

```
<input type="submit" id="submitID" value="ID" />
<input type="submit" id="submitClass" value="Class" />

<ul id="myList" class="myClass">
    <li>first list item</li>
    <li>second list item</li>
    <li>third list item</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $('#submitID').click(function(){
        $('#myList').append('<li>fourth list item</li>');
    });

    $('#submitClass').click(function(){
        $('.myClass').append('<li>fourth list item</li>');
    });
</script>
```

However, in my application, I am unable to append using the #myList ID reference and I can't figure out why.  I am dynamically rendering the ul and li elements and I have tried, as suggested, to use the following approach instead of the click event:

```
<script>
    $('#submitID').live('click', function(){
        $('#myList').append('<li>fourth list item</li>');
    });

    $('#submitClass').live('click', function(){
        $('.myClass').append('<li>fourth list item</li>');
    });
</script>
```

In FireBug console, I can interact with the object using .myClass, but not #myList.  For example, typing the following into FireBug console:

```
>>$('#myList').hide()
```

does not hide the #myList element as I would expect.  The console simply returns [].

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: do you have a live example of it not working? The only example provided was that of it working.

Comment: Your jsfiddle works for me. Check to see if your page has two or more elements with the same id.

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple items with the same `id`?

Comment: The returned [] means your ID is not matching anything, can you give an example ID?

Comment: Do you have an ID of `myList` anywhere else in the application?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are only five reasons I know of that addressing an ID won't work:

1. That ID is not really in the page like you think it is.
2. The element with that ID hasn't been loaded yet.
3. That ID is in the page more than once.
4. Your aren't actually requesting the ID you think you are.
5. Your ID contains invalid characters.
6. The element is in an `iframe` or `frame`.  Since this is actually a separate document from the parent document, searching some other document will not find elements in an embedded `iframe`.  You would have to search the `iframe` itself.

To check on the first item, if it's static HTML, then do a View/Source and make sure you have what you really expect to be in the page.

If it's dynamically generated HTML, then you will need to break in the debugger at a point where the object has been created and use the object inspector to make sure that it's really there with the appropriate ID.

Remember that IDs can only exist once in the page.  If there is more than one object with the same object, then getElementById or $("#xxxx") is undefined and will not return reliable results.

Comment: You forgot, "the ID is not a valid one", ie `<div id="Month:01"><div>`

Comment: jQuery does exactly what it's asked to do, even trying to find an ID that isn't in the DOM.  Thank you for forcing me to go back and study how I was rendering my IDs for that's where I found the bug.  In my application, jQuery was looking for an ID of "myList_123>".  Yes, including the greater-than symbol.  My alert of the id was showing me myList_123.

Comment: @Andrew - I added your new point.  I wasn't considering that one here because he told us the ID was "myList", but it's a good general point.

Comment: @Gunnar - Glad you found it.  For future reference, I added that one to the list too.

Comment: @Gunnar For future reference, The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name) defines a valid id explicitly, meaning !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ all make an id invalid.

Comment: +The element has not been loaded yet.

Comment: The element is inside iframe(frame). Of course it is another page but visually not, so you also can expect to find element.

Comment: @GareevKamil - I added the iframe reason.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer below, there is another possible cause: The jQuery `$` method has been overridden and is causing the problem.  This happened in our case when we added a 3rd party chat script.

Comment: For myself next time : check your ID doesn't start with '#'.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have 2 elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 2):

try putting the functions inside $(document).ready to make sure the DOM elements are loaded, like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#submitID').click(function(){
            $('#myList').append('<li>fourth list item</li>');
        });

        $('#submitClass').click(function(){
            $('.myClass').append('<li>fourth list item</li>');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This wont help, the .live makes this unnecessary as it'll make sure listeners are properly attached to matching elements, now and in the future, and the jQuery lookups won't happen until the elements are clicked, this is when the document is ready.

Answer (score 1):

I  found that some 3rd party libraries will override the jQuery `$` method.  In our case it caused the jQuery selector `#elementID` to be passed into `document.getElementById("#elementID")` which clearly won't find the item since `#` is a jQuery selector.  Function override below:

```
function $(element) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0, elements = [], length = arguments.length; i < length; i++)
      elements.push($(arguments[i]));
    return elements;
  }
  if (Object.isString(element))
    element = document.getElementById(element);
  return Element.extend(element);
}
```

We renamed the function from `$` to `$i3c` throughout that script file only.  This allowed all other jQuery-dependent java script to succeed in finding the element and fixed the issue.